# .NET MAUI Display a menu bar in a .NET MAUI desktop app using communitytoolkit.maui.markup

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

In Maui App how we can add menu bar Items by C# markup like this?

```
<ContentPage ...>
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="File">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"
                        Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Locations">
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Change Location">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Redmond, USA"
                            Command="{Binding ChangeLocationCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="Redmond" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="London, UK"
                            Command="{Binding ChangeLocationCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="London" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Berlin, DE"
                            Command="{Binding ChangeLocationCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="Berlin"/>
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
        <MenuFlyoutSeparator />            
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Location"
                        Command="{Binding AddLocationCommand}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit Location"
                        Command="{Binding EditLocationCommand}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove Location"
                        Command="{Binding RemoveLocationCommand}" />                            
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

we need using C# Markup for using conditional (in some case) to display menu items of the page - instead of use XAML like above. How can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    VM VM = new VM();
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
        CreateMenuBar();
    }
    void CreateMenuBar()
    {
        MenuBarItem menuElements1 = new MenuBarItem() { Text = "File" };
        MenuBarItem menuElements2 = new MenuBarItem() { Text = "Locations" };
        MenuBarItem menuElements3 = new MenuBarItem() { Text = "View" };
        MenuFlyoutSubItem subItemElements = new MenuFlyoutSubItem() { Text = "Locations" };
        MenuFlyoutSeparator menuFlyoutSeparator = new MenuFlyoutSeparator();
        List<MenuFlyoutItem> menuFlyoutItems1 =new() 
        {   
            new MenuFlyoutItem() 
            { 
                Text = "Redmond, USA",
                Command = VM.ChangeLocationCommand,
                CommandParameter = "Redmond" 
            },
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "London, UK" },
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Berlin, DE" } 
        };
        List<MenuFlyoutItem> menuFlyoutItems2 =new() 
        { 
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Add Location" },
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Edit Location" },
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Remove Location" }
        };
        List<MenuFlyoutItem> menuFlyoutItems3 =new()
        {
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Refresh" },
            new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Change Theme"}
        };
        
        menuElements1.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Exit" });
        foreach (var item in menuFlyoutItems1)
        {
            subItemElements.Add(item);
        }
        menuElements2.Add(subItemElements);
        menuElements2.Add(menuFlyoutSeparator);
        foreach (var item in menuFlyoutItems2)
        {
            menuElements2.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in menuFlyoutItems3)
        {
            menuElements3.Add(item);
        }
        MenuBarItems.Add(menuElements1);
        MenuBarItems.Add(menuElements2);
        MenuBarItems.Add(menuElements3);

    }
}
```

It works well.

Comment: Thanks Jianwei Sun alots!